# Reading in 4 bytes at a time

Tags: c++

I have a big file full of integers that I'm loading in.  I've just started using C++, and I'm trying out the filestream stuff.  From everything I've read, it appears I can only read in bytes, So I've had to set up a char array, and then cast it as a int pointer.

Is there a way I can read in 4 bytes at a time, and eliminate the need for the char array?

```
const int HRSIZE = 129951336;  //The size of the table
char bhr[HRSIZE];   //The table
int *dwhr;

int main()
{
    ifstream fstr;

    /* load the handranks.dat file */
    std::cout << "Loading table.dat...\n";
    fstr.open("table.dat");
    fstr.read(bhr, HRSIZE);
    fstr.close();
    dwhr = (int *) bhr;    
}
```

Comment: So your 'big file full of integers' is actually stored in binary? Are you accounting for endian-ness?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To read a single integer, pass in the address of the integer to the read function and ensure you only read `sizeof int` bytes.

```
int myint;

//...

fstr.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myint), sizeof(int));
```

You may also need to open the file in binary mode

```
fstr.open("table.dat", std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: @Daniel: `reinterpret_cast` is no 'safer' than a C-style cast.

Comment: It's equally safe at runtime, but safer when you read the code on a Sunday night before a deadline.

Comment: If you want to read raw integers, you need to deal with endian issues.  One technique is to store in network endian order which means you use `htonl` before writing and `ntohl` after reading.

Answer (score 4):

To read by 4 bytes from `ifstream` you could overload `operator>>` as follows (it is actually a partial specialization of the `basic_istream` class template so `istream_iterator` could use `operator>>` from it. Class `basic_ifstream` is used here to inherit all input file stream functionality from it):

```
#include <fstream>

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;    
struct uint32_helper_t {};

namespace std {
template<class traits>
class basic_istream<uint32_helper_t, traits> : public basic_ifstream<uint32_t> {
public:
    explicit basic_istream<uint32_helper_t, traits>(const char* filename, 
        ios_base::openmode mode ) : basic_ifstream<uint32_t>( filename, mode ) {}

    basic_istream<uint32_helper_t, traits>& operator>>(uint32_t& data) {
        read(&data, 1);
        return *this;
    }
};
} // namespace std {}
```

Then you could use it in the following way:

```
std::basic_istream<uint32_helper_t> my_file( FILENAME, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary );
// read one int at a time
uint32_t value;
my_file >> value;

// read all data in file
std::vector<uint32_t> data;
data.assign( std::istream_iterator<uint32_t, uint32_helper_t>(my_file),
  std::istream_iterator<uint32_t, uint32_helper_t>() );
```

Comment: @camh, the code explains the idea. We overload `operator>>` here for our type. Then use it explicitly in the first case and implicitly in the second case. What part of it is not clear?

Comment: There's more than an overloaded operator there. I cant see why you have basic_istream inheriting from basic_ifstream. It also doesn't compile (g++ 4.4.4).

Comment: @camh, I've added extra explanations in my answer. And I've made some fixes to make it more conformant. Hope this will help.

Comment: Ok. I've removed the -1. The problem must be in my head somewhere. I can't understand how basic_istream can inherit from basic_ifstream, since basic_ifstream already inherits from basic_istream.

Comment: The trick is that this is partial specialization of `basic_istream` template class, not standard `basic_istream`.

Answer (score 1):

your can do:

```
int i;
fstr.read((int*)&i, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This throws the following error -> 'error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(int*, long unsigned int)'
     f.read((int*)&i, sizeof(int));'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? By the way, your code (and this) assumes native endianness of the data.

```
const int HRSIZE = 129951336;  //The size of the table
int dhr[HRSIZE/sizeof(int)];   //The table

int main()
{
    ifstream fstr;

    /* load the handranks.dat file */
    std::cout << "Loading table.dat...\n";
    fstr.open("table.dat");
    fstr.read((char*)dhr, HRSIZE);
    fstr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
const int HRSIZE = 129951336/sizeof(int);  //The size of the table
int bhr[HRSIZE];   //The table

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream fstr;

    /* load the handranks.dat file */
    std::cout << "Loading table.dat...\n";
    fstr.open("table.dat");
    for (int i=0; i<HRSIZE; ++i)
    {
        fstr.read((char *)(bhr+i), sizeof(int));
    }
    fstr.close();

    // for correctness
    return 0;
}
```